# TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null vuejs on consecutive v-fors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am having this issue for hours now. I am rendering items on `<options>` for my `<select>` element using vuejs' v-for and when it rendered it gave me the type error. I tried changing my :key values but still having the same error and won't render the items that I needed.

Where did I make a mistake?

Code below:

This is my first `<select>` tag:

```
<vs-select placeholder="Gender"
      v-model="gender"
      color="#ffc640"
      class="col-span-2 mt-2 z-0"
      >
        <vs-option v-for="(gender, index) in $store.state.genders"
        :key="`${index}_gender`"
        :label="gender.label" :value="gender.name">
          {{ gender.label }}
        </vs-option>
    </vs-select>
```

Here is the next `<select>` tag:

```
<vs-select placeholder="Attainment"
      v-model="attainment"
      color="#ffc640"
      class="col-span-2 mt-2 z-0"
      >
        <vs-option v-for="(attainment, index) in $store.state.attainment"
        :key="`${index}_attainment`"
        :label="attainment.label" :value="attainment.name">
          {{ attainment.label }}
        </vs-option>
    </vs-select>
```

Here is the error:
[image]

For context, here are the objects

```
genders: [
{
  name: 'male',
  label: 'Man',
  value: '1-male',
},
{
  name: 'female',
  label: 'Woman',
  value: '2-female',
},
{
  name: 'lgbtq',
  label: 'Transgender',
  value: '3-lgbtq',
},
{
  name: 'nottosay',
  label: 'Prefer not to say',
  value: '4-nottosay',
},
```

],

```
 attainment: [
{
  name: 'high_school',
  label: 'High School',
  value: 'high_school',
},
{
  name: 'senior_high_school',
  label: 'Senior High School',
  value: 'senior_high_school',
},
{
  name: 'associate',
  label: 'Associate',
  value: 'associate',
},
{
  name: 'bachelor',
  label: 'Bachelor',
  value: 'bachelor',
},
{
  name: 'master',
  label: 'Master',
  value: 'master',
},
{
  name: 'doctorate',
  label: 'Doctorate',
  value: 'doctorate',
},
```

],

Here are my computed values:

```
attainment: {
  get() {
    return this.$store.state.user.attainment;
  },
  set(value) {
    this.$store.commit('setAttainment', value);
  },
},

gender: {
  get() {
    return this.$store.state.user.gender;
  },
  set(value) {
    this.$store.commit('setGender', value);
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Computed are functions that return a value according to the state. You cannot use them in v-model directives (but ': value' is correct). Reading the store state is prohibited also, you should use getters.
Your code can be something like this (remove computeds):

```
<vs-select placeholder="Gender"
      :value="$store.state.user.gender"
      @input="$store.commit('setGender', $event)"
      color="#ffc640"
      class="col-span-2 mt-2 z-0"
      >
        <vs-option v-for="(gender, index) in $store.state.genders"
        :key="`${index}_gender`"
        :label="gender.label" :value="gender.name">
          {{ gender.label }}
        </vs-option>
    </vs-select>
```

Anyway, it is not clean. Revise your store to use getters, listen to @input, and commit data changes.